# C# Selenium WebDriverWait doesn't appear to be waiting

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

I'm trying to test a page on which I'm performing a search. After performing the search, I pull out the SearchResults by first getting the table element, getting the table rows and then getting one or more from the rows to make my assertion over.

I've tried using WebDriverWaits in a number of different ways with no success. The only reliable way I've managed to select the items from the search result is to use a Thread.Sleep(3000). We're using the PrimeNG library for our Tables. The particular table that is loading is quite large, hence the need to put in some waits

**Selenium Info:**

- Selenium Version: 3.141.0
- Web driver type: ChromeDriver (89.0.4389.2300)
- Web driver version:

**Browser Info:**

- Browser type: Chrome
- Browser version: 90+ (on dev machine)

**Web Driver Initialization Code:**
I've split out my page and automation code by creating separate page objects and page drivers. This has been modelled on the [SpecFlow Books example](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Getting-Started/Getting-Started-With-An-Example.html)

**BasePage class**

```
public class BasePage
{
    protected IWebDriver Driver { get; }
    protected WebDriverWait Wait;

    public BasePage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        Driver = driver;
        Wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }

    public T As<T>() where T : BasePage
    {
        return (T)this;
    }

    public IWebElement PaginationFirst => Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("button.p-paginator-first.p-paginator-element")));
    public IWebElement PaginationLast => Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("button.p-paginator-last.p-paginator-element")));
    public IWebElement PaginationPageNumber => Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("button.p-paginator-page.p-paginator-element.p-highlight")));

    // Adding waits at this point meant the page elements were timing out due to not being in view.

    public virtual IWebElement ResultTable()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("table"));
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<IWebElement> TableLines()
    {
        return ResultTable().FindElements(By.CssSelector("tableRow"));
    }

    private void WaitUntilElementIsDisplayed(By locator)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        bool Condition(IWebDriver d)
        {
            IWebElement e = d.FindElement(locator);
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Displayed);
            return e.Displayed;
        }
        wait.Until(Condition);
    }
}
```

**UserListPage class**

```
public class UserListPage : BasePage
{
    //private readonly WebDriverWait _wait;
    //private readonly IWebDriver _driver;
    public UserListPage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "headingUsers")]
    public IWebElement PageTitle;
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "addUser")]
    public IWebElement AddUser;
    public IWebElement TxtSearchEverywhere => Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("txtSearchEverywhere")));
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "col-username")]
    public IWebElement ColUsername;
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "col-lastname")]
    public IWebElement ColLastname;
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "col-firstname")]
    public IWebElement ColFirstname;
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "col-hpicpn")]
    public IWebElement ColHpicpn;
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "col-facilitycount")]
    public IWebElement ColFacilitycount;
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "colRoles")]
    public IWebElement ColRoles;
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "col-identitycount")]
    public IWebElement ColIdentitycount;
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "colHasLogin")]
    public IWebElement ColHasLogin;
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "col-onlinelogin")]
    public IWebElement ColOnlinelogin;
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "col-loginstatus")]
    public IWebElement ColLoginstatus;

    public IEnumerable<UserRow> SearchResults => TableLines().Skip(1).Select(r => new UserRow(r));
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```html
<head>
    <body>
        <app-root>
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <main>
                        <app-role class=""><button id="addRole" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Add New Role</button>
                            <h2 id="roleTitle" class="mb-4">Roles</h2>
                            <peg-admin-list>
                                <p-table currentpagereporttemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries"
                                    ng-reflect-global-filter-fields="roleName,userFriendlyName,user">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="p-datatable-header ">
                                            <div class="table-header "><span class="p-input-icon-left"><i class="pi pi-search"></i>
                                                <input
                                                        id="txtSearchEverywhere" pinputtext="" type="search" placeholder="Search everywhere"
                                                        class="p-inputtext p-component"></span><span class="">
                                                    <p-selectbutton class="filter-flag">
                                                        <div role="group">
                                                            <div role="button" aria-pressed="true" title="isActive" aria-label="Active"
                                                                tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="Active">
                                                                <span class="p-button-label ">Active</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div role="button" aria-pressed="false" title="isActive" aria-label="Inactive"
                                                                tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="Inactive">
                                                                <span class="p-button-label ">Inactive</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div role="button" aria-pressed="false" title="isSystem" aria-label="Is System"
                                                                tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="Is System">
                                                                <span class="p-button-label ">Is System</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </p-selectbutton>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="p-datatable-wrapper ">
                                            <table role="grid">
                                                <thead class="p-datatable-thead">
                                                    <tr class="">
                                                        <th>
                                                            Role <p-sorticon ng-reflect-field="roleName"><i
                                                                    class="p-sortable-column-icon pi pi-fw pi-sort-alt"
                                                                    ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"></i>
                                                            </p-sorticon>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th> Reviewer Role Description <p-sorticon ng-reflect-field="userFriendlyName"><i
                                                                    class="p-sortable-column-icon pi pi-fw pi-sort-alt"
                                                                    ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"></i>
                                                            </p-sorticon>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                            Users Count <p-sorticon ng-reflect-field="usersCount"><i
                                                                    class="p-sortable-column-icon pi pi-fw pi-sort-alt"
                                                                    ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"></i>
                                                            </p-sorticon>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th> Is
                                                            Active <p-sorticon ng-reflect-field="isActive"><i
                                                                    class="p-sortable-column-icon pi pi-fw pi-sort-alt"
                                                                    ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"></i>
                                                            </p-sorticon>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th> Is System <p-sorticon ng-reflect-field="isSystem"><i
                                                                    class="p-sortable-column-icon pi pi-fw pi-sort-alt"
                                                                    ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"></i>
                                                            </p-sorticon>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                            Role Type <p-sorticon ng-reflect-field="roleType"><i
                                                                    class="p-sortable-column-icon pi pi-fw pi-sort-alt"
                                                                    ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"></i>
                                                            </p-sorticon>
                                                        </th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody class="p-datatable-tbody">
                                                    <tr class="tableRow ">
                                                        <td class="txtroleName">
                                                            <div>A new Role Test Test with a new name </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtuserFriendlyName">
                                                            <div>Check if can be seen in Admin2 bob bob bobby bob bob bob </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtusersCount">
                                                            <div>4</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtisActive">
                                                            <div> Yes </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtisSystem">
                                                            <div> No </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtroleType">
                                                            <div> Admin </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr class="tableRow">
                                                        <td class="txtroleName">
                                                            <div>A new Test Role</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtuserFriendlyName">
                                                            <div>Testing changes</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtusersCount">
                                                            <div>2</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtisActive">
                                                            <div>Yes</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtisSystem">
                                                            <div>No</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtroleType">
                                                            <div>Admin</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr class="tableRow ">
                                                        <td class="txtroleName">
                                                            <div>ADMS</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtuserFriendlyName">
                                                            <div> </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtusersCount">
                                                            <div>2</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtisActive">
                                                            <div>Yes</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtisSystem">
                                                            <div>No</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="txtroleType">
                                                            <div>Admin</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <p-paginator>
                                            <span class="p-paginator-current ">Showing 1 to 10 of 66
                                                entries</span>
                                            <button type="button" pripple=""
                                                class="p-paginator-first p-paginator-element p-link p-disabled p-ripple " disabled=""
                                                ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"><span
                                                    class="p-paginator-icon pi pi-angle-double-left"></span></button>
                                            <button type="button" pripple=""
                                                class="p-paginator-prev p-paginator-element p-link p-disabled p-ripple" disabled=""
                                                ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
                                                <span class="p-paginator-icon pi pi-angle-left"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <span class="p-paginator-pages ">
                                                <button type="button">1</button>
                                                <button type="button">2</button>
                                                <button type="button">3</button>
                                                <button type="button">4</button>
                                                <button type="button">5</button>
                                            </span>
                                            <button type="button">
                                                <span class="p-paginator-icon pi pi-angle-right"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button">
                                                <span class="p-paginator-icon pi pi-angle-double-right"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <p-dropdown styleclass="p-paginator-rpp-options">
                                                <div class="ng-tns-c56-0 p-paginator-rpp-options p-dropdown p-component"
                                                    ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
                                                    <div class="p-hidden-accessible ng-tns-c56-0"><input type="text"></div>
                                                    <span>10</span>
                                                    <div role="button">
                                                        <span class="p-dropdown-trigger-icon ng-tns-c56-0 pi pi-chevron-down"
                                                            ng-reflect-ng-class="pi pi-chevron-down"></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </p-dropdown>
                                    </div>
                                    </p-paginator>
                                    </div>
                                </p-table>
                            </peg-admin-list>
                        </app-role>
                    </main>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </app-root>
    </body>
</head>
```

**BrowserDriver class**

```
public class BrowserDriver : IDisposable
{
    private readonly BrowserDriverFactory _browserSeleniumDriverFactory;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly ConfigurationDriver _configurationDriver;
    private readonly Lazy<IWebDriver> _currentWebDriverLazy;
    private readonly Lazy<WebDriverWait> _waitLazy;
    private readonly TimeSpan _waitDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    private bool _isDisposed;

    public BrowserDriver(BrowserDriverFactory browserSeleniumDriverFactory, ConfigurationDriver configurationDriver, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _browserSeleniumDriverFactory = browserSeleniumDriverFactory;
        _config = config;
        _configurationDriver = configurationDriver;
        _currentWebDriverLazy = new Lazy<IWebDriver>(GetWebDriver);
        _waitLazy = new Lazy<WebDriverWait>(GetWebDriverWait);
    }

    public IWebDriver Current => _currentWebDriverLazy.Value;

    public WebDriverWait Wait => _waitLazy.Value;

    private WebDriverWait GetWebDriverWait()
    {
        return new WebDriverWait(Current, _waitDuration);
    }

    private IWebDriver GetWebDriver()
    {
        return _browserSeleniumDriverFactory.GetForBrowser(_configurationDriver.Mode);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (_currentWebDriverLazy.IsValueCreated)
        {
            Current.Quit();
        }

        _isDisposed = true;
    }

    public void Navigate(string urlPart = "")
    {
        if (!Current.Url.EndsWith(urlPart))
        {
            var baseUrl = _config.GetConnectionString("BaseUrl");
            Current.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            Current.Navigate().GoToUrl($"{baseUrl}/{urlPart}");
            RetryHelper.WaitFor(() => Current.Url.EndsWith(urlPart));
        }
    }

}
```

**RoleListPageDriver class**

```
public class RoleListPageDriver : IRoleListDriver
{
    private readonly BrowserDriver _browserDriver;
    private readonly IHomeDriver _homeDriver;
    private readonly RoleListPage _roleListPage;
    public IWebElement[] HeaderColumns;

   
    public RoleListPageDriver(BrowserDriver browserDriver, IHomeDriver homeDriver)
    {
        _browserDriver = browserDriver;
        _homeDriver = homeDriver;
        _roleListPage = new RoleListPage(_browserDriver.Current);
        HeaderColumns = new[]
        {
            _roleListPage.ColRole,
            _roleListPage.ColDescription,
            _roleListPage.ColUserCount,
            _roleListPage.ColIsActive,
            _roleListPage.ColIsSystem,
            _roleListPage.ColRoleType
        };
    }

    [AfterScenario()]
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _browserDriver.Dispose();
    }

    public bool Exists(IWebElement element)
    {
        return element.ElementExists();
    }

    public bool IsLoaded()
    {
        return _roleListPage.PageTitle.ElementExists();
    }

    public void Navigate()
    {
        _browserDriver.Navigate("role");
    }

    public void Search(string searchTerm)
    {
        _roleListPage.TxtSearchEverywhere.Search(searchTerm);
    }

    public void SortColumn(string selector)
    {
        var element = HeaderColumns.Where(h => h.Text == selector).ToList();
        if (element.Count > 0)
        {
            element[0].Clicks();
        }
    }

    public bool TableColumnHeadersExist()
    {
        return HeaderColumns.All(header => header.ElementExists());
    }

    public void RoleMenuExists()
    {
        _roleListPage.ColRole.ElementExists();
    }

    public bool RoleTitleExists()
    {
       return _roleListPage.PageTitle.ElementExists();
    }

    public void RoleListSortResultShouldBeAscendingDescending(string order)
    {
        switch (order)
        {
            case Constants.ListOrder.Ascending:
                _roleListPage.SearchResults.Take(5).Should().BeInAscendingOrder(r => r.RoleName);
                break;
            case Constants.ListOrder.Descending:
                _roleListPage.SearchResults.Take(5).Should().BeInDescendingOrder(r => r.RoleName);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void SearchResultsShouldContainMatchingItems(string searchTerm)
    {
        var searchResult = _roleListPage.SearchResults.Take(1).Select(s => s.RoleName).ToList();
        searchResult.All(str => str.Contains(searchTerm)).Should().BeTrue();
    }

    public void ClickOnFilterButton(string filterButton)
    {
        switch (filterButton)
        {
            case Constants.FilterButton.ActiveRoles:
                _roleListPage.BtnActive.Clicks();
                break;
            case Constants.FilterButton.InactiveRoles:
                _roleListPage.BtnInactive.Clicks();
                break;
            case Constants.FilterButton.IsSystemRoles:
                _roleListPage.BtnIsSystem.Clicks();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void AssertOnlyActiveRolesDisplayed()
    {
        _roleListPage.SearchResults.Take(5).All(r => r.IsActive == "Yes").Should().BeTrue();
    }

    public void AssertOnlyInactiveRolesDisplayed()
    {
        _roleListPage.SearchResults.Take(1).All(r => r.IsActive == "No").Should().BeTrue();
    }

    public void AssertOnlySystemRolesDisplayed()
    {
        _roleListPage.SearchResults.Take(1).All(r => r.IsSystem == "Yes").Should().BeTrue();
    }

    public void ClickOnLastPaginationButton()
    {
        _roleListPage.PaginationLast.Clicks();
    }

    public void AssertLastPageIsDisplayed()
    {
        int.Parse(_roleListPage.PaginationPageNumber.Text).Should().BeGreaterOrEqualTo(3);
    }

    public void AssertPageTitleIsDisplayed(string title)
    {
        _roleListPage.PageTitle.Text.Should().BeEquivalentTo(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your test?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Test code that is failing

Comment: I still don't see enough code to suggest a fix. Please have a look at [What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405792/3092298).

Comment: Is the `<body>` tag really a child element of the `<head>` tag? That would be completely invalid HTML, and I would start by fixing the invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The `BasePage.TableLines()` method could use an explicit wait:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<IWebElement> TableLines()
{
   var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
   var locator = By.CssSelector("table > tbody > tr");

   return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(locator));
}
```

This assumes there is some sort of change to the table while the data is loading. Without knowing what happens to the table while the results are loading, this is all I can provide.

If table rows are dynamically added as you scroll, that ends up being a whole different solution.